# Javascript events not working for Power Apps editable grid in model-driven app

Tags: powerapps, model-driven-app

I'm testing out the new(ish) editable grid control in a model-driven Power App and I don't seem to be able to get the Javascript events to fire.

There's nothing under limitations on the docs [Power Apps grid control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/the-power-apps-grid-control#known-issues-and-limitations)

The events work correctly if I switch back to the old EditableGrid control, so maybe there is still some feature gaps?